# Python 3 cant see string from imported module

Tags: python

I know this is a really simple issue but I can't get my head around modules and importing them.  I have a simple python program below...

**main.py**

```
# Import Function File
from func1 import source_func1

# Run function
source_func1()

# Print Variable 2 From Function
print(source_func1(var2))
```

**func1.py**

```
def source_func1():
    pass

# Set Variable 2
var2 = "This is my second variable"
```

When I run I am getting the following error...

```
print(source_func1(var2))
NameError: name 'var2' is not defined
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your `source_func1()` function *doesn't take an argument*. Why are you trying ta pass in `var2`?

Comment: Is `var2` inside of `source_func1()`?

Comment: If you want use variable in other modules import it. Or you can import all from module using from func1 import *

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to import `var2` explicitly, just like you imported the function:

```
from func1 import source_func1, var2
```

or

```
from func1 import source_func1
from func1 import var2
```

or you could import just the module and refer to both the function and the variable as attributes on the module:

```
import func1

print(func1.source_func1(func1.var2))
```

Note however, that you'll get an error in all these cases, because your `source_func1()` function *doesn't take an argument*:

```
TypeError: source_func1() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

If you formatted your question wrong and `var2` is actually a variable *inside* the function (in which case you need to fix your indentation), then you'll need to *return that value from the function*:

```
def source_func1():
    # Set Variable 2
    var2 = "This is my second variable"
    return var2
```

you can then directly print that returned value:

```
print(source_func1())  # the return value will be printed.
```

or set a *new* variable to whatever the function returned:

```
new_variable = source_func1()
print(new_variable)
```

That new variable *can* be named `var2` as well, but note that your `main.py` script has its own namespace; the variable named `var2` in this module is independent from the `func1.var2` name.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's starting to make sense.  I am confused by the arguments though, I just want source_func1 to set the string.  Where do the arguments come into it?

Comment: @fightstarr20: updated. Your question is *very unclear*; you did not appear to have formatted it correctly or explained what your expected outcome would be.

Answer (score 1):

The answer already given will work for you, but if you wanted to write your own function then inside the definition of `source_func1()` you need to return the value of `var2`, then outside you need to set `var2` to equal the function:

```
def source_func1():
    var2 = 10
    return var2

var2 = source_func1() #this defines var2 to equal whatever you put after the return
print (var2) # this should now print the value of var2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a single `import` statement:

Your `main.py`:

```
import func1

# call your function
func1.source_func1('argument')

# print your variable
print(func1.var2)
```

Your `func1.py`:

```
var2 = 'This is my second variable'

def source_func1(x):
    print(x)
```